# Why is my Picker's Focused+Unfocused event firing when an Editor is tapped in the same ViewCell?

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, picker

Using Xamarin.Forms. I have a `ListView` containing multiple `ViewCells` and in each one is a `Picker` and an `Editor`. Tapping the `Editor` fires `Editor_Focused`, but for some reason also fires `Picker_Focused` and `Picker_Unfocused`.  I use the `Picker_Unfocused` event handler to add some data to a `SQLite` database and then refresh the `ListView`, so I can't have it firing every time the `Editor` is tapped. Following along with breakpoints, my refresher method is called twice, because `Picker_Unfocused` is also called twice for unknown reaons. Also worth noting is that `Editor_Completed` won't fire no matter what I do.

Things I have tried:

- Adding a `TapGestureRecognizer` to the `Editor` which would set a property, which would then stop `Picker_Unfocused` from continuing its execution, but the `TapGestureRecognizer` never fires when the `Editor` is tapped.
- Assigning a value to a property when `Editor_Focused` is fired that would do the same as above. `Editor_Focused` does fire first, but then leaves that property in the "don't fire `Picker_Unfocused`" state even when the `Picker` actually needs to be used. Countering that by setting the property back to "do fire" state in `Picker_Focused` doesn't work, as the order goes `Editor_Focused` -> `Picker_Focused` -> `Picker_Unfocused` -> `Refresh list method`.

**Update:** Forgot to include any code.

ListView defined in XAML.

```
<ListView x:Name="ListView"
                      HasUnevenRows="True"
                      SelectionMode="None">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0,5,0,0">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Prop0}" 
                                           TextColor="DodgerBlue" 
                                           VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Prop1}" 
                                           TextColor="Black" 
                                           HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                           VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                                    <Label Text="Task Time:" TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="End"
                                       VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                                    <Picker x:Name="Picker" WidthRequest="80"
                                        Title="Enter time"
                                        FontSize="15"
                                        Focused="Picker_Focused"
                                        Unfocused="Picker_Unfocused"
                                        SelectedItem="{Binding Prop2}">
                                        <Picker.ItemsSource>
                                            <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                                                <x:String>0.25</x:String>
                                                <x:String>0.50</x:String>
                                                <x:String>0.75</x:String>
                                                <x:String>1.00</x:String>
                                            </x:Array>
                                        </Picker.ItemsSource>
                                    </Picker>
                                </StackLayout>
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                              IsVisible="{Binding Prop3}">
                                    <Label Text="Comments:" TextColor="Black" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                                    <Editor x:Name="Editor" Text="{Binding Prop4}" TextColor="Black"
                                            VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Focused="Editor_Focused"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </StackLayout>
                            <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                                    <MenuItem Text="Delete"
                                          x:Name="DeleteButton"
                                          Clicked="DeleteButton_Clicked"
                                          IsDestructive="True"
                                          CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                                </ViewCell.ContextActions>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```

Comment: You want to set events separately on every editor and picker right?

Comment: You can move the add some data to database and then refresh the ListView event to Picker's `SelectedIndexChanged` method. If you put the focus event, it will execute many times. And in the Editor , you can move the `focused` event to `Completed` event. If you changed component completely in the Editor, it will be executed.

Comment: If you put the Focused event in Viewcell of listview, you will got the strange behavior,  this issue was reported in github   https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/1600   https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/1906